# Cloudformation cfinit command from Program Files in windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

All I am trying to do is use cf-init and in my cloudformation template I have

```
command: '"c:\program files\.....exe" /p /f c:\path\file'
```

Basically when I look at the cfinit logs it says c:\program is not a valid command.

How do I escape this properly so I can get it executed.  I have searched high and low and tried a lot of variations for over 2 hours without success.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In Windows paths use a backslash ('') character, you must always remember to properly escape all backslashes by prepending another backslash whenever you refer to a Windows path in the AWS CloudFormation template.Example below:

```
C:\\SharePoint\\SharePointFoundation2010.exe
```

Refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-windows-stacks-bootstrapping.html) for more examples

Comment: I tried that as well, the SharePoint example does not have a path with a space in it. The problem lies in the path. In a regular command prompt you have to enclose the path in double quotes when the path has a space in it , i.e "Program Files" and that's what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the best way I found to do this is to use multiline

```
command: |
  "C:\Program Files\.......exe" /s /f c:\path\file.txt
```

Cheers for anyone else who ran into this